# How can i cache/preload all images of a Angular2 webapp?

Tags: angular, typescript, web-applications, angular2-services, preload

i am developing a webapp and it is almost finished. The problem is that there are a lot of images at the assets folder and when i am navigating the screen sometimes blinks changing the webapp background images.

Is it possible to preload all the resources or cache them in the browser in order to make the navigation smoother? Also,can i get feedback of the preload process in order to show a "loading" animation?

Thank you very much!

Comment: take a look at angular2-resource-preloader

Answer (score -1):

I didn't do it with images, but I'd try adding a Resolve guard to your home (default) route. Here's an example where I preload a large 45MB JSON file using the resolver https://github.com/Farata/angulartypescript/tree/master/chapter3/router-samples/src/app/resolver

In that app I use Angular Material `<md-progress-bar>` bar to show the progress.

Comment: The link seems to be broken.

Comment: Here's an updated one: https://github.com/Farata/angulartypescript/tree/master/code-samples/chapter4/router-advanced-samples/src/app/resolver

Comment: The link is broken again. For the love of Tim Berners-Lee just post the relevant code here.

Comment: Now there are two sets of code samples. The Angular6 version of this one is here: https://github.com/Farata/angulartypescript/tree/master/code-samples/Angular6/chapter4/router-advanced-samples/src/app/resolver
If you really love Tim Berners-Lee, you'll figure out the link for the Angular 5 version :)